# How to avoid Select statement in my for loop?

Tags: apex, after-trigger

```
 List<Checklist__c> newCheckLists = new List<Checklist__c>();  
 Map<Id, Account> legalStructAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT LegalStructure__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Legitimation__c WHERE Id IN :newLegitimations)]);

        Map<Legitimation__c, List<ChecklistTemplate__c>> ligitimatCheckListTemplate = new Map<Legitimation__c, List<ChecklistTemplate__c>>();

        for (Legitimation__c eachLegitimation : newLegitimations) {

            String legalStructure = legalStructAccount.get(eachLegitimation.Account__c).LegalStructure__c;
            ligitimatCheckListTemplate.put(eachLegitimation, [SELECT Name FROM ChecklistTemplate__c WHERE Entity__c ='legitimation' AND LegalStrucure__c includes (:legalStructure)]);
       }


        for (Legitimation__c eachLegitimationKey : ligitimatCheckListTemplate.keyset()){
             for (ChecklistTemplate__c eachChecklistTemplate : ligitimatCheckListTemplate.get(eachLegitimationKey)){
                Checklist__c checkList = new Checklist__c(
                    Name = eachChecklistTemplate.Name,
                    TemplateId__c = eachChecklistTemplate.Id,
                    LegitimationId__c = eachLegitimationKey.Id
                );
                newCheckLists.add(checkList);
            }
        }

    insert newCheckLists;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Added two section for both INCLUDE and IN

```
 List<Checklist__c> newCheckLists = new List<Checklist__c>();  
 Map<Id, Account> legalStructAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT LegalStructure__c 
                                                            FROM Account 
                                                            WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Legitimation__c WHERE Id IN :newLegitimations)]);

 Map<string,List<ChecklistTemplate__c>> ChecklistTemplateMap = new Map<string,List<ChecklistTemplate__c>>();
```

**If you want to use IN Clause:**

```
    // if you use IN Clause Block----Start
List<String> legalList = new List<String>(); 
for (Legitimation__c eachString : newLegitimations) {
    legalList.add(legalStructAccount.get(eachString.Account__c).LegalStructure__c);
}
For(ChecklistTemplate__c ckhList:[SELECT  Id,LegalStrucure__c,Name FROM ChecklistTemplate__c WHERE Entity__c ='legitimation' AND LegalStrucure__c IN : legalList]){
        if (ChecklistTemplateMap.containsKey(ckhList.LegalStrucure__c))
           {
             ChecklistTemplateMap.get(ckhList.LegalStrucure__c). add(ckhList);
           }
        else{
             ChecklistTemplateMap.put(ckhList.LegalStrucure__c,ckhList);
           }
       }
// if you use IN Clause Block----End
```

**If you want to use INCLUDE Clause**

```
// if you use INCLUDES Clause Block----Start
   string [] legalList = new List<String>();
   String legalString='';
    for (Legitimation__c eachString : newLegitimations) {
       for(String st : checkmap.get(eachLegitimation).split(';')){
           legalList.add('\''+ st + '\'');
     }       
}
system.debug('legalList---'+legalList);
String query = 'SELECT  Id,LegalStrucure__c,Name FROM ChecklistTemplate__c WHERE Entity__c ='legitimation' AND LegalStrucure__c INCLUDES(' + String.join(legalList, ',') + ')';
For(ChecklistTemplate__c ckhList: Database.query(query)){
        if (ChecklistTemplateMap.containsKey(ckhList.LegalStrucure__c))
           {
             ChecklistTemplateMap.get(ckhList.LegalStrucure__c).add(ckhList);
           }
        else{
             ChecklistTemplateMap.put(ckhList.LegalStrucure__c,ckhList);
           }
       }
// if you use INCLUDES Clause Block----End

   Map<Legitimation__c, List<ChecklistTemplate__c>> ligitimatCheckListTemplate = new Map<Legitimation__c, List<ChecklistTemplate__c>>();

        for (Legitimation__c eachLegitimation : newLegitimations) {

        String legalStructure = legalStructAccount.get(eachLegitimation.Account__c).LegalStructure__c;
        ligitimatCheckListTemplate.put(eachLegitimation,ChecklistTemplateMap.get(legalStructure));
   }
   for (Legitimation__c eachLegitimationKey : ligitimatCheckListTemplate.keyset()){
         for (ChecklistTemplate__c eachChecklistTemplate : ligitimatCheckListTemplate.get(eachLegitimationKey)){
            Checklist__c checkList = new Checklist__c(
                Name = eachChecklistTemplate.Name,
                TemplateId__c = eachChecklistTemplate.Id,
                LegitimationId__c = eachLegitimationKey.Id
            );
            newCheckLists.add(checkList);
        }
    }

    insert newCheckLists;
```

Comment: May I know why did you inlcude ** in between ?

Comment: just trying make it bold thats it

Comment: Thank you but I am using includes but as it is a string it is not matching my legalstructures like for example in legalstructure I get A, A,B and C but when I string it..I only get C but not the rest . Something like this, this is my problem and I cannot hard code the values inside like Includes(A,B) too. You check this for reference https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F00000008wp9IAA

Comment: where you are using include?  in this statement SELECT  Id,LegalStrucure__c,Name FROM ChecklistTemplate__c (Apply some filter if you can to reduce dataset)

Comment: yes. I am doing it in the checklist template SOQL

Comment: it is necessary you need use  include in the soql query?. because you can form list  of  string with legalstrructure__c by  iterating newLegitimations. I  tried to get the Map key of ChecklistTemplateMap with the string legal structure it is returning values.

Comment: updated code for both IN and INCLUDES.Check it

Comment: String query = 'SELECT  Id,LegalStrucure__c,Name FROM ChecklistTemplate__c WHERE Entity__c ='legitimation' AND LegalStrucure__c INCLUDES(' + String.join(legalList, ',') + ')';
 Won't this be an illegal assignment from List to String ?

Comment: You are asking in code compilation perspective?

Comment: Thank you for the answer but I am still looking to rework the subquery in the first map where I get the account from Legitimation but when change my subquery to       (SELECT Account__r.Id FROM Legitimation__c WHERE Id IN :newLegitimations) I get the following error as 'The inner select field cannot have more than one level of relationships '..

Comment: I am guessing I can write the sub query like this [SELECT Account__r.Id, Account__r.LegalStructure__c FROM Legitimation__c where Id = 'xxxxxx' GROUP BY Account__r.Id,Account__r.LegalStructure__c]

Answer (score 0):

If you iterate over your newLegitimations list twice, you can collect all the legal structures contained within the list, store them, then query all of your relevant checklist templates at once, map them based on their legal structure and then call from that map on the second iteration of newLegitmitations.

```
List<Checklist__c> newCheckLists = new List<Checklist__c>();  
Map<Id, Account> legalStructAccount = new Map<Id, Account>([SELECT LegalStructure__c FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT Account__c FROM Legitimation__c WHERE Id IN :newLegitimations)]);
Map<Legitimation__c, List<ChecklistTemplate__c>> ligitimatCheckListTemplate = new Map<Legitimation__c, List<ChecklistTemplate__c>>();
Map<String, List<ChecklistTemplate__c>> checklistMap = new Map<String,List<ChecklistTemplate__c>>();
String legalStructures = '';
    for (Legitimation__c eachLegitimation : newLegitimations) {
        String legalStructure = legalStructAccount.get(eachLegitimation.Account__c).LegalStructure__c;
        legalStructures += legalStructure+',';
   }

   legalStructures = legalStructures.removeEnd(',');

   for(ChecklistTemplate__c template : [SELECT Name, LegalStructure__c FROM ChecklistTemplate__c WHERE Entity__c ='legitimation' AND LegalStructure__c includes (:legalStructures)]){
       if(!checklistMap.containsKey(template.legalStructure__c) checklistMap.put(template.LegalStructure__c, new List<ChecklistTemplate__c>{template});
       else checklistMap.get(template.legalStructure__c).add(template);
   }

   for(Legitimation__c eachLegitimation : newLegitimations){
       String legalStructure = legalStructAccount.get(eachLegitimation.Account__c).LegalStructure__c;
       if(checklistMap.containsKey(legalStructure)) ligitimatCheckListTemplate.put(eachLegitimation, checklistMap.get(legalStructure));
   }


    for (Legitimation__c eachLegitimationKey : ligitimatCheckListTemplate.keyset()){
         for (ChecklistTemplate__c eachChecklistTemplate : ligitimatCheckListTemplate.get(eachLegitimationKey)){
            Checklist__c checkList = new Checklist__c(
                Name = eachChecklistTemplate.Name,
                TemplateId__c = eachChecklistTemplate.Id,
                LegitimationId__c = eachLegitimationKey.Id
            );
            newCheckLists.add(checkList);
        }
    }

insert newCheckLists;
}
```

Comment: I am trying to query on multipicklist so, I am trying to put includes in SOQL statement but not in and I get the error.

Comment: I've updated the code.  You may have to tweak some things after you query your checklist templates, but the initial logic should get you all the records you're attempting to query